# How to create text container in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am learning xaml/C#. I am trying to write lines of text using a container.
The closest example is this code in html

```
<div>
  <div>Line1</div>
  <div>Line2</div>
  <div>...</div>
 </div>
```

How can I do it in xaml.

Of course I can do it using simply TextBlock. The problem is that TextBlock does not allow me to add a kind of label like

```
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  text text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">     
        <TextBlock>Line1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Line2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Line3</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
```